# How do I send my application to background?

Tags: iphone, xcode, background, multitasking

I want to run my application in background ...

What things must I do to support this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what you really want.  You can't put your application into background, only the user can do that.  You should read the [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/technologies/iphone/whats-new.html) on the few things that an app is allowed to do when in background.  Location tracking, play music and continue VOIP calls.